# gem.add_dependency Jeweler how do you format a git source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, gemspecs

I'm trying to specify a git source in my Jeweler Rake file:

```
   gem.add_dependency 'myapp', :git => "git@github.com:myaddress/myapp.git", :branch => "mybranch"
```

but I hit a format error. Do you know how to format this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can add a dependency for a git repo. It doesn't work like Bundler afaik.

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#dependencies

Comment: So it seems you really gotta publish the gem before building another one on top of it. I got here because I wanted to make a gem Rails 3.2 compatible (but Rails 3.2 isn't out yet). I was gonna point it to Rails edge but it doesn't seem possible. I guess I'll need to leave it in the Gemfile for now!